# Npm version not showing

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal

I recently bought a new laptop and I have already installed node.js and when I try to check, only the node version appear and the npm version is blank as seen from the image below, Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I try to uninstall and install back node.js this issue still appears.

[image]

Comment: try `npm version` or just `npm`. Which outputs does this commands produce?

Comment: Hi, it still show the same thing as shown in the picture above

Comment: I found it weird that the version is not showing up, is there a way to check if it is install? the node version did show up for me

Comment: How did you install `npm`? Please give us your step-by-step explaination so we can try to examine the problem.

Comment: Hi, I install npm by installing the Node.js from this link: https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and I follow the on-screen instructions to install it